# What number does 8e3 evaluate to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I encountered this code today:

```
b = setTimeout(function () {
    // do some javascript stuff here
}, 8e3)
```

The timeout is set to `8e3`.  What time does this equate to in milliseconds, and why would anyone choose this strange notation?  The code appears to be fully functional.

Comment: This code had been previously minified, so I'm sure that's where the notation came from.  Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`8e3` is eight times ten to the power of three, that is, 8000. This is called [scientific (or exponential) notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). Just imagine the "e" stands for "*10^".

In this case there isn't much point in using that notation, but once you start getting to larger numbers, exponential notation becomes more readable. To figure out how much "1000000000" is you'd have to count zeros, but 1e9 is immediately obvious.

Comment: +1 Good Explanation. Learned something today. Had no idea I could use this in javascript :D

Comment: @brenjt: It would be strange if you couldn't use it in JavaScript ;) It is (almost) everywhere (in every programming language), I believe ;)

Comment: Not in every single language, but in many of most popular ones.

Comment: @zizozu: I'm not sure I agree. In most C-like languages, `8e3` is a floating-point constant, and can't be implicitly converted to an integer. JavaScript is different, because it doesn't distinguish floating-point numbers from integers. (There are a few other such languages, but still, I'd hardly say that this is the case "everywhere".)

Comment: @ruakh Doesn't that mean you can use 8e3 where you'd use a floating point number "almost everywhere"?

Comment: @Jimmy: It doesn't mean that, no -- but I'll grant that it doesn't mean the opposite, either. However, `setTimeout` is clearly designed to take an *integer* argument (since that's the only reason it would use milliseconds).

Comment: @ruakh: `setTimeout` attribute format is not relevant to this discussion. What I said is that exponential notation is very common. If you could name one language without it (just lets agree to exclude esoteric and highly limited languages ;)), I would be grateful.

Comment: @zizozu: No, what you said is that "it" is very common -- leaving it open what exactly "it" meant. So I said that I'm not sure I agree: if all you mean is "some sort of concept of exponential notation", then that's true, but if you mean "the ability to use `8e3` to mean `8000` in a context expecting an integer" (as in the answer), then it's not true.

Comment: @ruakh: JavaScript only has a single numeric type, so 8e3 should be no different from 8000.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: Yes, exactly. As I said. :-)

Comment: --- Now it makes sense... 1e3 != 0x1e3, face-palm big time.

Answer (score 19):

This is called *floating point notation* or *scientific notation*. It is 8×10³, which is **8000 miliseconds**. The e stands for 10th exponent. Let me give you some more examples:

```
1e3    = 1000        // 1×10³
1e0    = 1           // 1×10⁰
1e-1   = 0.1         // 1×10⁻¹ -> Works also for the negatives
1.23e9 = 1230000000  // And really makes sense to shorten big numbers
```

*There is also an wikipedia article on that topic: **[Scientific Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)***

Answer (score 9):

`8e3` is exactly `8000`, so the time is exactly 8 seconds.

This could be chosen (eg. by some code minifiers) because it takes exactly 3 characters instead of 4 to represent `8000`. Which means you gain 25% in terms of space in this single place :)

And this is not "strange" notation, it is just another way of expressing numbers: [Floating point notation](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/fpnotati.htm)

Answer (score 9):

8*10<sup>3</sup> = 8000 ms which is 8 seconds