# How can I increment a number after every 1 second using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Everything is working but i m unable to set the delay. Also , I will like to stop the increment after a particular interval. kindly please help me

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var number = parseInt($('#test').text().trim());
    while (number != 1000) {
        number++;
        $("#test").text(number);
        var number = parseInt($('#test').text().trim());
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<p id="test">1</p>
```

Comment: Google: setTimeout setInterval

Comment: I had already used it but it didn't worked. @Amit
    setTimeout(1000);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increment integer by 1; every 1 second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586890/increment-integer-by-1-every-1-second) , [Exactly similar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26271084/3639582)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setInterval` to add `delay`.

See comments inline in the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var number = parseInt($('#test').text(), 10) || 0; // Get the number from paragraph


    // Called the function in each second
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('#test').text(number++); // Update the value in paragraph

        if (number > 1000) {
            clearInterval(interval); // If exceeded 100, clear interval
        }
    }, 1000); // Run for each second
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4kmrk3dy/)

Comment: The increment runs after a second, can i make it more faster

Comment: @AmanjotKaur Yes, change the `1000` of the `clearInterval` to some lower value

Comment: @PraveenKumar There was. Removed now

Comment: @Tushar look my answer *edit*, maybe sound new to you :P

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)** instead. `innerText` also comes to be an editable property, so you can also try this:

```js
var loop = setInterval(function(){
   ++$("#test")[0].innerText >= 1000 && clearInterval(loop)
}, 10)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test">0</p>
```

### Edit: Using loops

With the new operators [function *](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and [yield *](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) in **ECMAScript ES6** you can do exactly what you're doing using loops. Note: If you are learning Javascript, you must read more about its [functioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).

```js
function* incrementFn(){
   var number = +$("#test").text();
   while(number != 1000){
      yield number++;
      $("#test").text(number)
   }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   var incrementLoop = incrementFn();
   var interval = setInterval(function(){
      if(incrementLoop.next().done) clearInterval(interval)
   }, 10)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test">0</p>
```

<kbd>Note</kbd> that this will return a syntax error if your browser still uses `ES5`. Modern browsers already have `ES6`, you can enable it following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008366/using-ecmascript-6).

Comment: Yes, i also used your method. may i know what is 1e3

Comment: @AmanjotKaur 1e3 is equivalent to 1000, 1e6 is equivalent to 1000000 :). [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180772/what-number-does-8e3-evaluate-to)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/oc2h4qpn/1)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
       var number = parseInt($('#test').text().trim());
       if (number < 1000) {
          $('#test').html(number+1);
       }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `setInterval`:

```js
$(function() {
  var test = $('#test'); // cache object
  setInterval(function() {
    test.text(1 + (+test.text())); // +('3') <-- 3, parsing string to number
  }, 1000);// (in miliseconds) repeat every 1 second
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test">1</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  (function() { 
    let counterEl = document.getElementById('counter');
    let number = 0;
    let interval = setInterval(() =>  {
      counterEl.innerText =  number++; 
      if(number > 10) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 1000);// repeat every 1 second
  })();
```

```html
   <div id="counter">0</div>
```